# Complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the parabola in the complex plane given by $y = x^2 /16 + 3$. Let $\alpha$ be a smooth curve from $-4 + 4i$ to $4 + 4i$ along the parabola. Compute $\int_\alpha \frac{1}{\zeta} d\zeta$.

My book says: $\int_\alpha f = \int_\alpha f(\zeta) d\zeta = \int^b _a f(\alpha(t)) \alpha'(t) dt$.

Does this mean that I need to parameterize the parabola first? Would $\alpha(t) = t + i (t^2 /16 + 3)$ be a good choice?

Furthermore I suppose that the integral lies between $-4 + 4i$ and $4 + 4i$. Or would it be easier to split up?

Answer (score 2):

You could parametrise the curve.  I think you will then find that the integral is pretty messy.

A better approach: the curve in question does not cross the negative part of the real axis (draw a sketch to confirm this).  So we can use an antiderivative to integrate:
$$\int_\alpha \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}=[{\rm Log}\,\zeta]_{\rm start}^{\rm end}
  ={\rm Log}\,(4+4i)-{\rm Log}\,(-4+4i)\ .$$
I'll leave you to calculate the logarithms for yourself.  The logarithm I am referring to is the principal complex logarithm defined by
$${\rm Log}\,(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta\ ,\quad -\pi<\theta\le\pi\ .$$

Comment: From which follows that we can use the antiderivative if the curve does not cross the negative part of the real axis? What would be the difference if the curve would cross the negative part of the real axis?

Comment: See if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136064/complex-antiderivative/136108#136108) helps.